# Testing Internals In Go

Tags: unit-testing, go

The recommended golang test method signature format is:

```
func TestMxxxx(t *testing.T) {

}
```

I have noticed if I use 'Testmxxxx', it simply skips the tests. Now, if I have two function in a package, one name myFunc (as private, not exported), and another Myfunc(exported). What will be the approach to write separate test method for each of them?

Comment: The name of the test isn't directly related to what it's testing. Call them what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was actually looking for a standard way. Such as 'TestInternalmxxx' or similar, which practice other golang devs might already be .

Answer (score 3):

You can use underscores. E.g.

```
func Test_mxxxx(t *testing.T) {
    // ...
}
```

This should run just fine.

Comment: nice idea, didn't try this way.